# Problem with saving BMP file without compression (BI_RGB) and indexed color palette

Tags: java, graphics2d, javax.imageio, bmp

I have a problem with saving BMP file. I need to save not compressed BMP image (BI_RGB) with 4 color indexed palette.

I have a BufferedImage object called `image` (it is ok because after saving to png it looks right). Then I create IndexColorModel and convert BufferedImage:

```
    IndexColorModel colorModel = new IndexColorModel(
            4, // 4 bits - max 16 colors
            4, // 4 colors in palette
            new byte[]{(byte) BITMAP_COLOR_1[0], (byte) BITMAP_COLOR_2[0], (byte) BITMAP_COLOR_3[0], (byte) BITMAP_COLOR_4[0]},
            new byte[]{(byte) BITMAP_COLOR_1[1], (byte) BITMAP_COLOR_2[1], (byte) BITMAP_COLOR_3[1], (byte) BITMAP_COLOR_4[1]},
            new byte[]{(byte) BITMAP_COLOR_1[2], (byte) BITMAP_COLOR_2[2], (byte) BITMAP_COLOR_3[2], (byte) BITMAP_COLOR_4[2]});

    BufferedImage grayImage = new BufferedImage(
            image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED,  
            colorModel);

    Graphics2D gfx2d = grayImage.createGraphics();
    gfx2d.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    gfx2d.fillRect(0, 0, grayImage.getWidth(), grayImage.getHeight());
    gfx2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    gfx2d.dispose();
```

Now, when I'm saving this to png it looks right, the problem is when I'm trying to save it to BPM, like that:

```
private byte[] createBmpBytes(BufferedImage image) {
    byte[] data = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("BMP").next();
        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);
        writer.setOutput(ios);
        BMPImageWriteParam param = (BMPImageWriteParam) writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        param.setCompressionType("BI_RGB");
        param.setTopDown(true);
        writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
        writer.dispose();
        ios.flush();
        data = baos.toByteArray();
        ios.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Result is the following: https://ibb.co/Qb0WxC0

When I save it to png it looks like that: https://ibb.co/WpmYLcP

Is somewhere a mistake in parameters or Java doesn't support this format of BMP? Is there any external library which could save BMP in such a format?

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal working example. First to check, if it's working without custom colorModel

Comment: I think you need to use `BI_RLE4` (4 bits/16 colors) or `BI_RLE8` (8 bits/256 colors) with indexed (palette) images. There's no way to store these without RLE compression.  If you use `BI_RGB`, your image has to be "true color". It's possible to include palette in a true color BMP file, but the image data will still be full 24 or 32 bit. I'm not sure if this is what you want?

Comment: The images https://ibb.co/Qb0WxC0, https://ibb.co/WpmYLcP no longer exist

Answer (score 1):

To save BMP I used Apache Commons Imaging and result is as I expected. Image has been saved as BI_RGB (withous compression) and has included 4 color palette from IndexColorModel.

```
private byte[] createBmpBytes(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    byte[] imageBytes = null;
    try {
        imageBytes = Imaging.writeImageToBytes(bufferedImage, ImageFormats.BMP, params);
    } catch (ImageWriteException | IOException e) {
        log.error("Image generating error", e);
    }
    return imageBytes;
}
```